# Select multiple data from SQLite database based on multiple tags

Tags: java, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an SQLite database with some to do lists.
Each to do list, there is a column for tag.

Here is a sample layout of my SQLite database

[image]

Let's say I want to select the to do lists with tags containing "Me" and "Mom" (ie "Buy groceries", "Study" and " Holiday trip"), how do I do this?

I have consider this, but I dont think it works.

```
public   getToDoLists (String [] tags) {
    this.db = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = " SELECT * FROM "
            + TABLE_NAME
            + " WHERE "
            + COL2 + " ='" + tags + "'";
    c = db.rawQuery(query, null);  
    .......
    .......
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a simple query.
You are passing the tags that you search for as a String array.
One option is to use a `for` loop which will iterate all the tags of the array and for each tag run a query, but this is bad for performance.

The option that I suggest is to join all the tags separated with `,` in a string and pass it to a query which in turn will split it with a recursive CTE and run a `SELECT...` statement with `EXISTS...` to fetch the matching rows:

```
public Cursor getToDoLists(String[] tags) {
    String joinedTags = TextUtils.join(",", tags);

    String query =
            "WITH " +
            "  list(tag) AS (SELECT ?), " +
            "  cte(tag, value) AS ( " +
            "    SELECT SUBSTR(tag, 1, INSTR(tag || ',', ',') - 1), " +
            "           SUBSTR(tag, INSTR(tag || ',', ',') + 1) " +
            "    FROM list " +
            "    UNION ALL " +
            "    SELECT SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value || ',', ',') - 1), " +
            "           SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value || ',', ',') + 1) " +
            "    FROM cte " +
            "    WHERE LENGTH(value) > 0 " +
            ") " +
            "SELECT t.* " +
            "FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " t " +
            "WHERE EXISTS ( " +
            "  SELECT 1 FROM cte c " +
            "  WHERE ',' || REPLACE(t.Tags, ', ', ',') || ',' LIKE '%,' || c.tag || ',%' " +
            ")";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    return db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {joinedTags});
}
```

I use `REPLACE(t.Tags, ', ', ',')` in the sql statement because I see that the separator of the tags in the column `Tags` is `', '` and not `','`.
If I'm mistaken then change `REPLACE(t.Tags, ', ', ',')` with just `t.Tags`.

The method `getToDoLists()` must be placed inside your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and you can call it from your activity class like:

```
Cursor c = openHelper.getToDoLists(new String[] {"Me", "Mom"});
```

and it returns a `Cursor` with the rows matching your criteria, which you can iterate.

To use `TextUtils.join()` you will need this import:

```
import android.text.TextUtils;
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0ece9daf34006fbb9a0301de802ca7e4) of how this works in SQLite.

Comment: Hi, thanks. This works. I do need to change this, "REPLACE(t.Tags, ', ', ',')" to this "t.Tags"

Comment: if I want to use

SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONTAINS (Tags, 'Dad');

why it gives error 'no such function CONTAINS'

Comment: @EhsanRosdi because there is no function CONTAINS() in SQLite. Here is a list of functions supported by SQLite: https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html Use INSTR() instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp for that.

Note, that regexp function is not provided by default, https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#regexp:

> No regexp() user function is defined by default and so use of the
> REGEXP operator will normally result in an error message. If an
> application-defined SQL function named "regexp" is added at run-time,
> then the "X REGEXP Y" operator will be implemented as a call to
> "regexp(Y,X)".

You can load regexp function with ICU extension: https://sqlite.org/src/artifact?ci=trunk&filename=ext/icu/README.txt. With that:

```sql
select
  "To do list"
from table

where 1==1
and (    "Tags" regexp '.*\bMom\b.*'
      or "Tags" regexp '.*\bMe\b.*'  )
```

ICU regexp syntax reference: https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html#regular-expression-metacharacters